# How to deploy new program including .NET files

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, installation, release

A while ago I have created a program in visual studio and installed it on another computer which I was needed to install before a lot of .NET files, framework files, sqla and sdk files and more, and just then, I was able to activate the program.
It was a windowsForms application on desktop- so this is what I have tried.

Please how can I make it easier?

How can I install the program on another computer including already all of the files?

Instead of installing them separately?

Maybe on dll?

I dont know but im sure there is an easier way doing it

Comment: Consider [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953320.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is not clear, you can create an [MSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) using [WixToolSet](http://wixtoolset.org/), [InstallShield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020.aspx),[Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/), etc.
For instance, if you are using Wix, you can install the [Wix Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WiXToolset) in visual studio, create a wix project and the compile it into an MSI with all the files you want included in the final install.
You can find many sources on the net that can give you tutorials to get you start, like [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with)